# How to find value inside multidimensional array without looping?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array stored in **$accounts** variable :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [account] => ACR016
            [desc] => Salary
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [account] => ACR017
            [desc] => Bonuses
        )
)
```

I'd like to find/get the "desc" value by using its "account" inside **$accounts**,

In SQL i will go like this :

```
SELECT desc FROM table WHERE account = 'ACR016';
```

How to do that with PHP without do the SQL query (because the array already stored in variable) and without looping ?

Comment: Any specific reason you want this "_without looping_"?

Comment: Sometimes people want to have a functional approach although this will loop behind the scenes. You can always use an [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-description)

Comment: @brombeer it will loop thousand times, i'm avoiding looping mainly to reduce loading time

Comment: @Remy, i'm avoiding the loop because it will take more time to be processed, also would you please specified the using of array_filter in this case ?

Comment: `array_filter($accounts, fn ($subarray) => $subarray['account'] == 'ACR016');` (note [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php#functions.arrow) are a PHP 7.4 thing). The nature of the problem is unfortunately iterative (you want to do something for all the values you obtained) unless you know something about your data up front to access an array index or other keys in constant time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php for this.

As this is a builtin function it should perform better than doing your own loop.

Example:

```
$accountDescriptions = array_column($accounts,'desc','account');
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [ACR016] => Salary 
    [ACR017] => Bonuses
)
```

Alternatively you can use:

Example:

```
$accountDescriptions = array_column($accounts,null,'account');
```

Then you will get all data keyed with account instead of numeric index.